# VOIP: Tampering RTP data

Tags: voip

Is it possible to take an encrypted RTP stream, one that has no integrity, and somehow edit the conversation to produce another conversation, i.e. make the person say something they didn't mean to? I don't mean static nonsense.

Comment: Data without integrity *by definition* can be altered so it means something different, so your question doesn't mean anything. Perhaps if you edit to clarify?

Comment: I question whether the editing of this question didn't alter its meaning. @dylan7 probably needs to weigh in.